# Get the original filename of symlinks in nginx

Tags: variables, nginx

From another script i got some generated symlinks.

```
2QGPCKVNG1R -> /anotherdir/movie1.mp4
HJS7J9ND2L5 -> /anotherdir/movie2.mp4
LKA6A9LA7SK -> /anotherdir/movie3.mp4
```

Displaying these files in NGINX works fine, but I'd like to rename the files at download via content disposition.

Question is how do i get the original filename in nginx variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible at all. Is that another script yours or under your control? You can generate an additional nginx config file with a `map` block with the same script where you can describe a ruleset for mapping an URI value to the `Content-Disposition` header value (or you can write an additional script to do it with `readlink -f <symlink>` command:

```
map $uri $content_disposition {
    ~/2QGPCKVNG1R$    movie1.mp4;
    ~/HJS7J9ND2L5$    movie2.mp4;
    ~/LKA6A9LA7SK$    movie3.mp4;
}
```

And then include that file to the main nginx config:

```
include /path/to/content-disposition-map.conf;
server {
    ...
    add_header Content-Disposition $content_disposition;
```

Another way I see is to use [`lua-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and a LUA script like

```
map $symlink_target $content_disposition {
    ~/([^/]*)$    $1;
}

server {
    ...
    set_by_lua_block $symlink_target {
        local result = io.popen("/bin/readlink -n -f " .. ngx.var.request_filename)
        return result:read()
    }
    add_header Content-Disposition $content_disposition;
```